# Determining where a value lies from a list of intervals (synthetic solution)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list `l` of increasing values, for example

```
import numpy as np
l=np.linspace(0.,1.,10)
```

For a number `a=0.225`, I want to find the index `i` such that `l[i]<a<l[i+1]`. Of course, I can do

```
for j in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[j]<a<l[j+1]:
        i=j
        break
```

but is there a more synthetic way to do this?

Comment: Look at `searchsorted`: `np.searchsorted(l, 0.225)` returns `3` here.  As the name implies, this requires your interval array to be sorted.

Comment: @user3483203  Didn't see your comment till I posted. Would you like to post it?

Comment: @Divakar nope, your answer is good!

Comment: @Divakar TY for stressing that there is the need to subtract `1` if we want to first interval to be labeled `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, for `l` being sorted, we can use `np.searchsorted` -

```
np.searchsorted(l,a,'right')-1
```

Or with `np.digitize` -

```
np.digitize(a,l,right=True)-1
```

Comment: great, and I guess there is no need to specify `'right'` if I know for sure that `a` will be between the first and the last value of `l` .

Comment: @3sm1r Yeah if you are sure that `a` falls in between and not on one of the bins, you can go with the default `left` one.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure python solution, there is the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module:

```py
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> a = list(range(1, 10))
>>> bisect_left(a, 3.5)
3
```

or with numpy:

```py
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
>>> bisect_left(l, 0.225)
3
```

> [`bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)
>
> Locate the insertion point
>   for x in a to maintain sorted order. The parameters `lo` and `hi` may be
>   used to specify a subset of the list which should be considered; by
>   default the entire list is used. If `x` is already present in `a`, the
>   insertion point will be before (to the left of) any existing entries.
>   The return value is suitable for use as the first parameter to
>   `list.insert()` assuming that a is already sorted.
>
> The returned insertion point `i` partitions the array `a` into two halves
>   so that `all(val < x for val in a[lo:i])` for the left side and `all(val >= x for val in a[i:hi])` for the right side.