# Vectorize a lookup between two numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cython

I am trying to find a way to vectorize the following for loop using numpy. This for loop is making my code really drag. The problem that I am having is that I need to look up a value sitting in the dictionary, d, based on the index where the value,val, falls in a range within the array, row.

```
for i in range(len(row)-1):
    if row[i]<val<=row[i+1]:
        return d[i]*row[-1]
```

I would imagine that I could use np.where and np.logical_and to get between two numbers in the array, but then I need the index to grab the value from a dictionary, and that is the part that I just can't seem to figure out without the loop.

Comment: Seems very relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118469/.

Comment: That looks like it might do the trick, if I wrap the dictionary's get method in np.vectorize... Let me do some testing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Divakar's comment, I think that the right answer is to replace the entire for-loop with this numpy monstrosity:

```
 np.vectorize(d1.get)((np.searchsorted(row[:-1],vals,side='left'))-1)*row[-1]
```